# JsDoc group multiple @typedef into one configuration file

Tags: javascript, types, documentation, jsdoc

I have a project where I have to define multiple jsDoc's `@typedef` for describing multiple custom object types required by functions in the project.

I'm wondering if I could group all these `@typedef` together into a single module/configuration file and reference them project-wide?

Otherwise I would have to write these custom `@typedef` into multiple modules, and given that most of these have many properties this could create very big comment blocks that makes the modules ugly and difficult to read.